# Facebook metatags not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

I placed my Facebook metatags inside my app like this:

```
#application.html.erb
<head>
  <title>sdff</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Test" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://fullimageurl" /> 
</head>
```

But I don't know why the `facebook-share` is not showing the image and title

Comment: `content_for?(:head)` will return true only if the page being rendered includes `root-page.html.erb` where the content capture logic is defined with `<% content_for :head do %>..<% end %>`. Quite likely the partial is not part of the page.

Comment: It's being called, I'm checking the html.

Comment: If it is being called, no reason for it to not get included in the layout. Add `  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("content_for :head block being called");
  </script>` within the content capture block and load the page again; you should see the alert box if it is being called.

Comment: @MatheusLima did you checked the html output in browser ? , also try it in url debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/